# LEFT JOIN SQL. Need help finding issue

Tags: sql, sas

I have 4 tables with different kinds of data.

Orders(StudentId, StoreId, AdvisorId, Date)

Students(StudentId, FirstName, LastName, Address)

Stores(StoreId, StoreNAme, StoreAddress)

Advisors(AdvisorId, AdvisorName, AdvisorAddress)

My Orders table has 14 million records. All I am trying to do is to get
Orders.*, Student.FirstName, Student.LastName, Student.Address, Stores.StoreNAme, Stores,StoreAddress, Advisors.AdvisorNAme, Advisors.AdvisorAddress

using the below LEFT JOIN query. I believe the result should only contain 14 million records like the Orders. But what I get is way more 14 million.

Can someone please tell whats wrong with this query

```
Select Orders.*, Student.FirstName, Student.LastName, Student.Address, Stores.StoreNAme, Stores,StoreAddress, Advisors.AdvisorNAme, Advisors.AdvisorAddress from Orders
LEFT JOIN Students on Orders.StudentId = Students.StudentId
LEFT JOIN Stores on Orders.StoreID = Stores.StoreId
LEFT JOIN Advisors on Orders.AdvisorId = Advisors.AdvisorId
Where Orders.Date > 'Jan102014'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There may be multiple records in `Students` OR `Stores` OR `Advisors` corresponding to `Orders`

Comment: "Where Orders.Date > 'Jan102014'" is it valid?

Comment: There are multiple records in Orders table for a given student, but not the other way

Comment: @ray: Thats the format in which my Orders table has the date. For now, lets assume it valid as the query compiles fine

Comment: Don't your inner tables have duplicated IDs ? Do they have PK/UK constraints for ID columns ?

Comment: What is this actually being done in?  Why so many tags?

Comment: @Dmitry Nikiforov: They dont have any duplicates. But not all records in Orders table have corresponding records in the Students OR Stores OR Advisors tables. Thats the reason I am using a left join.

Comment: @Joe: I am running it in SAS EG. I spent quite a bit of time on SQL a year back. Donno if its issue with left join in SAS? (I dont think so. And I dont get what am I doing wrong either)

Comment: If you're doing this in SAS, then remove the [tag:mysql] and [tag:oracle] tags, as they're not relevant (unless you're actually running it via pass-through to one of those), in which case you should add that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your question, looks like you want list of students, stores for every order placed. so you should use inner join with orders and not left join.

```
Select 
Orders . *,
Student.FirstName,
Student.LastName,
Student.Address,
Stores.StoreNAme,
Stores,
StoreAddress,
Advisors.AdvisorNAme,
Advisors.AdvisorAddress
from
Orders
    INNER JOIN
Students ON Orders.StudentId = Students.StudentId
    INNER JOIN
Stores ON Orders.StoreID = Stores.StoreId
    INNER JOIN
Advisors ON Orders.AdvisorId = Advisors.AdvisorId
Where
Orders.Date > 'Jan102014'
```

Comment: What If There are not all Orders in any other table ?

Comment: i am assuming each order has been placed by a student from a store with an advisor and so each order placed should have all these details. that's my thinking but not sure how you have rationlised.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` won't be any more helpful than `LEFT JOIN` if all details are `NOT NULL`. The initial query should do the trick, as long as `StudentId`, `StoreId` and `AdvisorId` columns are primary keys in corresponding tables.

Comment: i was assuming there may be cases when there is no advisor, so that's why inner can come in handy.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I did try the inner join before trying the left join. Inner join gives me around 6 million records, which was definitely wrong.

Comment: tell us how your database is structured? what do you want to retrieve and we can tell you what you are doing wrong

Comment: I found some inconsistencies with the data in the Advisors table, which was leading to producing redundant/duplicate/unwanted results. I fixed the Advisors table data and it works fine now.